# Handling subsets of shared resources in Simpy

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm using the Simpy discrete event-simulation in Python to simulate a factory. The `resource` class allows me to simulate resources that can be used by a limited and fixed number of processes at a time (e.g., a gas station with a limited number of fuel pumps). Roughly: processes have to request these resources to become a user, and have to release them once they are done (e.g., vehicles arrive at the gas station, use a fuel-pump, if one is available, and leave when they are done).

A resource has a limited and fixed number of slots that can be requested by a process. If all slots are taken, requesters are put into a queue. If a process releases a slot, the next process is popped from the queue and gets one slot.

In my case, I have a list of processes that have to use some shared machines. Each process is associated with a fixed *subset* of the machines that is allowed to use. If this subset were the same for every process then the problem it's easy to implement with the built-in methods, but I'm having trouble with this variation of the problem.

I've tried to make each available machine as a individual `resource` with capacity of one (instead of one single `resource` with capacity equal to the total of available machines) and use the `any_of` method to asign each process to the first available machine of its corresponding subset of allowed machines. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Is there a easy or natural way to implement this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Store` with machines instead. If a machine has a capactiy of 1, the items in the store don't need to be `Resource` instances (as in the example) but can be normal objects (instances of `object()` are sufficient).

```py
import simpy


def user(name, env, machine_store):
    machine = yield machine_store.get()
    with machine.request() as req:
        yield req
        print(name, 'got machine', machine, 'at', env.now)
        yield env.timeout(1)
    yield machine_store.put(machine)
    print(name, 'done at', env.now)


env = simpy.Environment()
machines = [simpy.Resource(env, 1) for i in range(2)]
machine_store = simpy.Store(env, len(machines))
machine_store.items = machines
for i in range(3):
    env.process(user(i, env, machine_store))
env.run()
```